ClassNotFoundException Error When Integrating Hilt in Android Application
I am trying to integrate Hilt for dependency injection. I have added all the dependencies, but I am getting the following error in the log:

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.example.stockmarket.App package com.example.stockmarket: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.stockmarket.App"


libs.versions.toml
[versions]
agp = "8.4.1"
kotlin = "2.0.0"
hilt = "2.44"
hilt-compile = "1.2.0"
hilt_lifecycle_viewmodel = "1.0.0-alpha03"
hilt_navigation_compose = "1.2.0"

[libraries]
hilt-android = { group = "com.google.dagger", name = "hilt-android", version.ref = "hilt" }
hilt-android-compiler = { group = "com.google.dagger", name = "hilt-android-compiler", version.ref = "hilt" }
hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel = { group = "androidx.hilt", name = "hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel", version.ref = "hilt_lifecycle_viewmodel" }
hilt-compiler = { group = "androidx.hilt", name = "hilt-compiler", version.ref = "hilt-compile" }
hilt-navigation-compose = { group = "androidx.hilt", name = "hilt-navigation-compose", version.ref = "hilt_navigation_compose" }

[plugins]
android-application = { id = "com.android.application", version.ref = "agp" }
jetbrains-kotlin-android = { id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android", version.ref = "kotlin" }
kotlinAndroidKsp = { id = "com.google.devtools.ksp", version.ref ="ksp" }
hiltAndroid = { id = "com.google.dagger.hilt.android", version.ref ="hilt" }
compose-compiler = { id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.compose", version.ref = "kotlin" }
kotlin-serialization = { id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.serialization", version.ref = "kotlin" }

build.gradle (App)
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.android.application)
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrains.kotlin.android)
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlinAndroidKsp)
    alias(libs.plugins.hiltAndroid)
    alias(libs.plugins.compose.compiler)
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlin.serialization)
}

dependencies {

    implementation(libs.androidx.core.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.lifecycle.runtime.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.activity.compose)
    implementation(platform(libs.androidx.compose.bom))
    implementation(libs.androidx.ui)
    implementation(libs.androidx.ui.graphics)
    implementation(libs.androidx.ui.tooling.preview)
    implementation(libs.androidx.material3)
    implementation(libs.androidx.room)
    implementation(libs.androidx.room.ktx)
    implementation(libs.retrofit)
    implementation(libs.retrofit.converster)
    implementation(libs.okhttp)
    implementation(libs.okhttp.logging)
    implementation(libs.opencsv)
    implementation(libs.lifecycle.viewmodel.compose)
    implementation(libs.material.icons.extended)
    implementation(libs.accompanist.swiperefresh)
    implementation(libs.hilt.android)
    implementation(libs.navigation.compose)
    implementation(libs.kotlinx.serialization.json)
    ksp(libs.hilt.android.compiler)
    ksp(libs.hilt.compiler)
    implementation(libs.hilt.lifecycle.viewmodel)
    implementation(libs.hilt.navigation.compose)
    testImplementation(libs.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.espresso.core)
    androidTestImplementation(platform(libs.androidx.compose.bom))
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.test.junit4)
    debugImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.tooling)
    debugImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.test.manifest)
}


build.gradle (Project)
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.android.application) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrains.kotlin.android) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.hiltAndroid) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlinAndroidKsp) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.compose.compiler) apply false

}

Application class
@HiltAndroidApp
class App: Application()

Manifest file
    <application
        tools:replace="theme,label,allowBackup,icon"
        android:name=".App"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.StockMarket"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.StockMarket">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

Tried with latest hilt version, not helping

Have you added all required dependencies in build.gradle (app)? you have just mentioned plugins block above.

Yes, updated dependency as well

You use the heavily outdated hilt version 2.44. Upgrade it to the current version (as of the time of writing that is 2.51.1).
Now you can weed out the artifacts you do not need anymore. In the version catalog remove these:

hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel
hilt-compiler

In your module level gradle file remove the following:

ksp(libs.hilt.compiler)
implementation(libs.hilt.lifecycle.viewmodel)

With this updated Hilt setup the error shouldn't occur anymore.

Looks like your app requires a multi-dex setup:
Follow the guide from here: https://developer.android.com/build/multidex
Just make small changes in the dependencies and the Application class and you are good to go.
It may come from a huge number of dependencies you've added. But it's ok if your app is big in the future

This doesn't seem to be related, it won't fix the problem.
